# Nested Hashmap: Alternative to putIfAbsent which does not requires null check and manual get?

Tags: java, hashmap, nested-map

I have a nested `HashMap` looking like this: `HashMap<String, HashMap<String,Object>>`.

I created a `add` method to fill the `HashMap`

```
private void add(String currentVersion, String targetVersion, Object object) {
    HashMap <String, HashMap <String, Object >> nestedMap = definedUpdatePlans.putIfAbsent(currentVersion, new HashMap());
    if (nestedMap == null) {
        nestedMap = definedUpdatePlans.get(currentVersion);
    }
    nestedMap.put(targetVersion, object);
}
```

As you see, I'll add the nested map if absent. If it was already present, I'll get the current value as return value. In case if it was absent, `putIfAbsent` returns `null` which requires me to do a null check and a manual get to populate the variable.

This seems not very clean, but I wouldn't know a better way.

Is there a way to add a value if not existing and keep working with the new or pre existing value in a more fluent way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `computeIfAbsent`:

```
private void add(String currentVersion, String targetVersion, Object object) {
    definedUpdatePlans.computeIfAbsent(currentVersion, k -> new HashMap())
                      .put(targetVersion, object);
}
```

It returns:

> the current (existing or computed) value associated with the specified key, or null if the computed value is null

Comment: Exactly this. Thank you.